# Shiny app can't access SQLite db on RStudio Connect Server: "database is locked"

Tags: r, sqlite, shiny

I've deployed an R Shiny app on a R Studio Connect Server and I'm simply trying to get data from a SQLite database which I've included in the deployed application.

When I run the app locally (through the runApp function), everything works fine and the data is fetched from the database.

When I run the app from the R Studio Connect Server, I have the following error message: "Warning: Error in : database is locked" I do not understand why the db is locked or how to unlock it.

The tree of the deployed application looks like this

```
- app.R
- data/
|-- database.db
```

The code of my shiny app is as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(RSQLite)

loadData <- function() {
    path_to_db <- "data/database.db"
    # Connect to the database
    db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), path_to_db)
    # Construct the fetching query
    isin_static_info_tb = "isin_static_info_table"
    query <- sprintf("SELECT * FROM %s", isin_static_info_tb)
    # Submit the fetch query and disconnect
    data <- dbGetQuery(db, query)
    dbDisconnect(db)
    data
}

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    actionButton(inputId = "displayTable", label = "Show table"),
    
    tags$hr(),
    
    tableOutput(outputId = "table")
    
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    data <- eventReactive(input$displayTable, {
        return(loadData())
    })
    
    output$table <- renderTable(data())
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Maybe a stupid suggestion, but have you ensured that your file/folder level permissions are set appropriately?

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Actually, I do not know how to check for file permissions as the file is deployed on the RStudio Connect Server... I'm only a "publisher" to this server, do you know how I could check for permissions?

Comment: I just checked for permissions on the database file with the function file.access("data/database.db", mode = 0/1/2/4). It returned 0 (so success) for mode 0/2/4, as it does when I run my app locally (before deployment), so I would say the permissions are ok...